# Cant install unity-control-center after update to 14.04

Tags: unity, software-center, settings

I was running 12.04 then upgraded to 14.04 and tried to reinstall unity-control-center but i get:

```
unity-control-center: Depends: libpulse-mainloop-glib0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but 1:4.0-0ubuntu11 is to be installed bash: syntax error near unexpected token ('me@server:~$ Depends: libpulse0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but 1:4.0-0ubuntu11 is to be installed
bash: syntax error near unexpected token ('me@server:~$ Depends: libxi6 (>= 2:1.2.99.4) but 2:1.7.1.901-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

How can i resolve this? I am installing this because i cannot open it via menu->system settings

Comment: Go to a terminal, try refreshing the APT package list by running, `sudo apt-get update` and then try installing the unity-control-center. Running `sudo apt-get upgrade` after refreshing the APT package list might help.